# If a ring $R$ is a field, must $R$ be a unitary ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, definition

If a ring $R$ is a field, then does it automatically imply that $R$ is a unitary ring?

Thank you.

Comment: Hey, the answer to your question is yes. That said, you could have easily deduced that yourself. I do not mean in any conceivable way that you shouldn't use this site to your full advantage, to help clarify ideas or solve problems, but it is not a place for "quick questions" per se. You have asked over 5 questions in the past hour, the majority of which I guarantee you could have figured out yourself (have faith in yourself!).

Comment: Yes, unless you are asking about the mythical [field with one element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element) (which actually isn't a field), of course.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$